# How to run blur-admin?

Tags: git, blur-admin

While running the Blur-Admin using

> gulp serve

The following error is hitting:

[image]

I already installed bower by using

> npm install -g bower

and also gulp by using

> npm install -g gulp

Then clone git blur-admin by **git clone https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin.git**

Then run as per  [installation guide](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/)

Unfortunately, I didn't get suitable solution for this (in [blur-adminDocs](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/001-getting-started/) and also in google).

Why this problem/errors occurring? Please help me to run this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ok, fixed it. The problem is with the node packages - they need other packages too which are not specified in the package.json:

> npm install --save eslint-config-defaults
>
> npm install --save eslint-plugin-react

After running these commands, **gulp serve** will start the local dev server and open the theme in the browser.

However, there are still error messages, for the missing "babl-eslint" package. However, after installing this package the gulp serve command will exit with an error again.

Edit 1:

This can also Solved by: delete this file **C:\Users{username}\.eslintrc**